# Searching directory over a network

Tags: files-and-directories, networking, file-transfer

I have a network drive mapped on my Windows machine.  I need to read data from the network that is nested in a few directories below the root.  Example is "G:/Data/folder01/data/date_name/values.csv".  There are hundreds of folders below /Data and hundreds below /folder001.  That is many under "foldernnn".  The following command can take up 140 seconds as search with the wild card commences.

`file = FileNames["G/Data/folder*"];`

I have tried to explore creating a remote session, but this is new to me and I do not see a lot of help related to that here.

Any suggests?  One thought is to run a shell command, which goes pretty fast.  Again, I need help in doing that.

Comment: What do you do with the output of `FileNames`? Also, does "G/Data/folder*" really work on your system, ie you don't need "G:\\Data\\folder*"?

Comment: Hi - I need the path so I can then download a file with a known name after I get the path.  Note that "G:\\Data\\folder*" and "G:/Data/folder*" can be used interchangebly in Mathematica.  Try "C:\\|*" vs. "C:/*" and you will get the same result.

Comment: OK so you are just missing the colon in your code. Got it. Would you share the rest of the code you use, for context and clarity?

Answer (score 2):

I found something that works and changes the search time from 94 seconds to 0.48 seconds.  This is to use the `RunProcess` function in Mathematica.  This looks like the following in my application.

```
Result = RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", 
  "dir G:\\Data\\folder* /t"}]
```

When I do this, I get a rules based result that can be parsed to find the directory I need using a `Select` command.